# Android error during build - "default public constructor with no argument must be declared". What's the cause?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

Android studio returned an error during build, even after running Clean, and rebuilding:

> A default public constructor with no argument must be declared if a
>   custom constructor is declared.

I could not find a line number, nor a file referenced. I have no idea what causes this, as there's no indication from the build where or what the cause of this is.

Comment: Can you paste the error log in pastebin and share the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a custom constructor like this

```
public class Doge extends RealmObject {
     public Doge(String name) {
       ...
```

Then you must also have a default constructor with no additional parameters.

```
public Doge() {
    // default values possible since 2.0.2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
public class ModelResult {
String Ques;
String Ans;

public String getQues() {
    return Ques;
}

public void setQues(String ques) {
    Ques = ques;
}

public String getAns() {
    return Ans;
}

public void setAns(String ans) {
    Ans = ans;
}


public ModelResult(String ques, String ans) {
    super();
    Ques = ques;
    Ans = ans;
}

public ModelResult() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

your missing part may be this

```
public ModelResult() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! My issue was that there was no file or line number to reference the problem. I'm going to make a slight edit to your class as it pertains to a RealmObject.

Comment: I had accepted it, but this error pertains to an extension of RealmObject. My edit did not get accepted, so I marked the other one as the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around and couldn't find anything on the web, which is why I posted this question. My hope is that it'll point others who are experiencing this in the correct direction.

As it turns out, the cause was a new Realm model I'd just created that hadn't exposed a default constructor. As soon as it occurred to me, I added the default constructor to the Realm model, and the build error disappeared.

So, check your Realm models for missing default constructors if you're getting this error during a build!